# java-script Catch block is not working in the fetch api response of promise

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

When i am trying to fetch some data from the external api than , assume that the internet connection is not available than it must show the error from the catch block but it is not showing it. I cannot console log anything from catch block so i am not able to show no internet connection error.

if internet is off due to any reason than how i get this info that internet is off.
        i was expecting from the catch block this msg.

```js
class EasyHTTP {
  get(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => resolve(data))
        .catch(err => reject(err));
    });
  }
}

const http = new EasyHTTP;

http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `.then` is used for error handling. Change it to

```
http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(data => console.log(data), err => console.log(err));
```